# Making menu id's fixed value

Tags: php, wordpress

My problem is that I am using a theme for Wordpress which automatically makes the menu id's the same as the title of that menu.

This means that if I use characters not in the English alphabet A-Z, the scrolling won't work for these menus. Been sitting for several hours trying to figure it out, what to edit and how.

```
<?php
$section_menu = zels_get_option('portfolio');
$id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $section_menu['name'])); ?>
```

I suspect I should be able to change this code in some way to make the menu anchor # a fixed value and not based of the title of the section, but then again I can't be sure.

If you need any more information just let me know, the site is locally hosted though.

All help will be largely appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$id = 'your-fixed-value-here';`

Comment: Indeed, I felt this was the solution too but after updating, it is exactly the same :(.

Comment: Then you will need to show more code. Where is that ID used?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6Fe1S3eh Here we go, wouldn't let me paste it here as it was too long. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing the `$id` variable should work. Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: It's the AWE wordpress theme if that's of any help. What do you mean by replacing it?

Comment: I meant changing the value of the variable. Looking at the theme you would need to change the ids in the menu and the way it handles them in the template. I tried to download the theme to take a better look but the download seems broken.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. The DL link is broken in most places for some weird reason, I managed to find it at last but it took some time. Uploaded it here for you https://ufile.io/4435 :).

Comment: Can you give me an example of one your menu names that is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the header file and all of the files within the sections folder

**header.php**

Change line 97 from

```
echo '<li><a href="#' . sanitize_title_with_dashes( $section_name ) .'">' . $section_name . '</a></li>';
```

To

```
echo '<li><a href="#' . sanitize_title( $section_name ) .'">' . $section_name . '</a></li>';
```

For the files in the sections folder change line 7 from

```
$id = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $section_menu['name']));
```

To

```
$id = sanitize_title( $section_menu['name'] );
```

The `sanitize_title` function will replace white space with dashes and change accent characters to their non accent equivalents.

Comment: You're a god damn life savior, I cannot thank you enough. This solved my issue perfectly!! have a great day, and life.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer has helped please mark it as correct so it can help others.